# How can I write this without so many floats?

Tags: python

```
float(float(1)/float(i) * float(score))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming Python 2.x: `1.0 / i * score`

The main case you need to worry about is the division because in Python 2.x, division is defaulted to integer division. In order to have floating-point division, either the dividend or divisor needs to be a float, hence the `1.0`. Thus, `1.0/i` will be a float, and multiplying a float by score (which can either be an integer or float) will result in another floating-point number.

In python 3.x, however, division defaults to floating-point division, so `1 / i * score` would work.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is simply `float(score)/i` in Python2. If one operand is a float, then the result will be a float too ,so code like `score/float(i)` or `1.0*score/i` works as well.

You can also put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your .py file and you have float division by default. This means you can write `score/i` and it will be a float, like in Python3.

Comment: And `from __future__ import divison` together with `score / i` is the only way to make the same code work with `score` and `i` being `decimal.Decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

`1.0 * score / i;` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm totally wrong, a simple `1.0 / i * score` should result in a float. I'm not sure if that's Python 3 only.